# Wampserver not loading project

Tags: windows-11, wamp64

I have just installed wampserver on a new machine: Windows 11; [wampserver homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBOoN.png)
I loaded a joomla site into the jfd folder and called it in a firefox browser ( although the result is the same on chrome) and I just get the index listing instead of the browser opening install package of the Joomla site.

I uninstalled the wampserver, made sure that all the C++ files were loaded and on the new machine, started the machine and reinstalled the server. I am getting the same result, just the index list and not opening in a brower.

I am running the same wampserver on my Windows 10 machine with no problem.
Also, when I enter "localhost/jfd", The OS just downloads the zip file to  "downloads" and that's it.
I'm wondering is there is a problem with Windows 11 or, if not, what is going on?

Comment: You need to create a Virtual Host for all your projects, not just a subfolder. [See this for info on how to do that](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,127757)